# Using jQuery replaceWith() to replace selected text with input text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to let the user be able to enter a phrase from the body text, and then have that text replaced with whatever the user would like. I believe [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) would be best here, however I am not totally sure how to implement it.

Here is my HTML for the input area.

```
<h2>Replace</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Original:</td>
        <td>
            <input id="original" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>New Text:</td>
        <td>
            <input id="newtext" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input id="replace" type="button" name="save" value="Replace" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

and I would like the user to be able to enter a word or phrase from the `#text`(body) and then enter in the new text part of the input, what text they would like to replace the original text with.

The one thing I am having a tough problem with is taking into account that the user can enter any word or phrase from the "original" text and replace the "original" text with anything they would like.

I thought something like

```
$("table").click(function(){
    $("#text").replaceWith("anything the user wants");
});
```

Thank you!

ALL

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#red").click(function(){
    $("#text").css("color","red");
  });
  $("#blue").click(function(){
    $("#text").css("color","blue");
});
  $("#green").click(function(){
    $("#text").css("color","green");
});

  $("#times_new_roman").click(function(){
    $("#text").css("font-family","'Times New Roman'");
}); 
  $("#courier").click(function(){
    $("#text").css("font-family","courier");
}); 

  $("#comic_sans").click(function(){
    $("#text").css("font-family","'Comic Sans MS'");
}); 
  $("#arial").click(function(){
    $("#text").css("font-family","Arial");
}); 
    $('input[name="decoration"]').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == 'bold'){
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) $("#text").css('font-weight', "bold");
            else $("#text").css('font-weight', "normal");
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'italic'){
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) $("#text").css('font-style', "italic");
            else $("#text").css('font-style', "normal");
        }

    });
      $('input[name="font"]').bind('keypress', function (event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("[0-9]");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
       event.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }
});

$("#up").click(function () {
    var currentSize = $("#text").css("font-size");
    currentSize = currentSize.replace(/[^\d.]/g, "");
    currentSize++;
    if(currentSize < 10 || currentSize > 80){
        alert("Font-size between 10 and 80 only!");
    }
    else {
        $("#text").css("font-size", "" + currentSize + "px");
    }
});

$("#down").click(function () {
    var currentSize = $("#text").css("font-size");
    currentSize = currentSize.replace(/[^\d.]/g, "");
    currentSize--;
    if(currentSize < 10 || currentSize > 80){
        alert("Font-size between 10 and 80 only!");
    }
    else {
        $("#text").css("font-size", "" + currentSize + "px");
    }

});

$('input[name="font"]').on("keyup change", function () {
    var newSize = $(this).val();
    if(newSize < 10 || newSize > 80){
        alert("Font-size between 10 and 80 only!");
    }
    else {
        $("#text").css("font-size", "" + newSize + "px");
    }
});

    });

</script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>INFO 2300 - HW1</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" title="StyleSheet" /> 
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <h1>Super Cool Javascript Text Editor</h1>
        <form id="controlForm" class="controls" action="index.php" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
            <div id="color">
                <h2 class="test2">Font Color</h2>
                <label for="red">Red</label> 
                <input type="radio" name="color" value="Red" id="red" /><br />
                <label for="blue">Blue</label> 
                <input type="radio" name="color" value="Blue" id="blue" /><br />
                <label for="green">Green</label> 
                <input type="radio" name="color" value="Green" id="green" /><br />
            </div>

            <div>
                <h2>Font Family</h2>
                <!-- Giving specific names, then generic ones, is useful for font families
                    because not everyone has every font. -->
                <label for="courier">Courier</label> 
                <input type="radio" name="family" value="courier,monospace" id="courier" /><br />
                <label for="times_new_roman">Times New Roman</label> 
                <input type="radio" name="family" value="times new roman,serif" id="times_new_roman" /><br />
                <label for="arial">Arial</label> 
                <input type="radio" name="family" value="arial,sans-serif" id="arial" /><br />
                <label for="comic_sans">Comic Sans MS</label> 
                <input type="radio" name="family" value="comic sans ms, sans-serif" id="comic_sans" /><br />
            </div>
            <div id="font">
                <h2>Font Size</h2>
                <input name="font" type="text" value="15"/>px
                <br /><span id="sizeWarning"></span>
            <div>
                </div>
                <h2>Text Decoration</h2>
                <label for="bold">Bold</label> 
                <input type="checkbox" name="decoration" value="bold" id="bold" /><br />

                <!-- Added for italic -->
                <label for="italic">Italic</label> 
                <input type="checkbox" name="decoration" value="italic" id="italic" /><br />
            </div>

            <div>
                <h2>Search Features [Already Implemented]</h2>
                <input id="search" type="text" name="search"/>
            </div>

            <div>
                <h2>Replace</h2>
                <table>
                <tr><td>Original: </td><td><input id="original" type="text" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>New Text: </td><td><input id="newtext" type="text" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2"><input id="replace" type="button" name="save" value="Replace" /></td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>

        </form>


        <form id="myform" class="test" action="saveFile.php" method="post">
        <div id="saveResult" class="saveResult">
            <input name="hiddentext" type="hidden" />
            <input name="settings" type="hidden" />
            <input name="savebutton" type="submit" value="Save file" />
        </div>
        </form>

        <div id="text">
        <?php
            //reads in the file
            $file = file("lorem.txt");
            foreach($file as $line){
                echo "<p>".$line."</p>";
            }
        ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?
If I understood right, you do not want the user to be able to edit the first inputbox?

You can use "readonly" property. 

Also can you show use the `#text` element?

Comment: see where the input #original is? well on my page I have a paragraph of text. I want the user to enter a phrase or word from that paragraph of text(#text) and then be able to replace that word or phrase, with whatever they enter in input # replace box. I will post my entire html/js so you can see. its kinda a lot tho

Comment: `replaceWith()` is for replacing DOM objects. You want String.replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like

```
if (!RegExp.escape) {
    RegExp.escape = function (s) {
        return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
    };
}
jQuery(function () {
    $('#replace').click(function () {
        var text = $('#original').val();
        if (text) {
            var regex = new RegExp(RegExp.escape(text), 'g');
            $('h2').text(function (i, text) {
                return text.replace(regex, $('#newtext').val())
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rmMhN/)

You can use a simple regex to replace the searched string in the target

Comment: I think this answers the question. You could use sugarJS to save having to write your own escape function (and a hundred other things JavaScript ought to have) :-)  http://sugarjs.com/api/RegExp/escape

Comment: ah thank you. just a few questions. If I do not want the user to enter any html tags or weird stuff, just allow letters, numbers, and spaces in the $.replace() part correct? Also, where in the code did you make it so the user can enter anything in the replace part? That is really tripping me up and id love to know for future projects

Comment: I think you can allow user to enter anything to replace a string, if you sanitize the input properly it should not cause any problem... in this case since we are using `.text()` to replace the string it should be safe enough

Comment: ah ok, so with .text, they cannot enter anything funny correct? can i use an alert and regexp, to only allow a-zA-z0-9 and if something else id decided when the function is clicked do an alert('only alphanumerical characters allowed') somehow? Currently when I enter <html> anything with tags, the tags arent stripped.

Comment: @user3321452 they can enter html tags but instead of rendering those it will print the values as it is like if you type `<b>bold</b>` instead of showing **bold** it will show `<b>bold</b>`

Comment: ah yes, just saw that, was checking google. Thank you very much for the help, really appreciate it. was a little confused. Thank you and have a good day

Answer (score 0):

You can just use 
             $('#text').text('anything you want') ;

Comment: $("table").click(function(){
    $("#text").replaceWith("anything the user wants");
}); so where anything you want, how can I make that so that anything the user enters, just use $this or?

Comment: Use $('#newtext').val() inside replace with

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, what you want to do is replace a single word inside div#text, where each line of text are wrapped inside `<p></p>` tags. (Is that intentional? If not, tell me at comment and I will add answer to how you keep it all in one P tag.)

The steps to answer this is:

1. Get the text of the element
2. Do a search and replace
3. Set the new text on the element #text

To do so:

```
function replaceTextAtDiv(){
    var div_text = $("#text").text();
    var textToReplace = $("#original").val();
    var newText = $("#newtext").val();
    div_text.replace(textToReplace, newText);
    $("#text").text(div_text);

    /* OR - In One Line

    /$("#text").text($("#text").text().replace($("#original").val(), $("#newtext").val()));*/
}
```

**Suggestion**
To put all the text inside on `<p></p>` wrapper. Do it like this:

```
<?php
    //reads in the file
    $file = file("lorem.txt");
    $string = "";
    foreach($file as $line){
        $string = $string . "\n" . $line; //Take away [  . "\n" ] if it generates 2 line breaks.
    }
    echo "<p>".$string."</p>";
?>
```